# How do I create a new table in SQL with using the UNION ALL function?

Tags: google-bigquery, create-table, union-all

I am working on my google analytics course case study and I am trying to create a new table on Big Query- SQL by combining 12 datasets. I keep getting this error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "bikeshare_total" at [1:14]

Please see the below query. I tried different variations but I'm getting the same error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "bikeshare_total" AS (
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Jan2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Feb2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.March2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.April2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.May2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.June2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.July2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.August2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Sep2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Oct2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Nov2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Dec2021`)
```

Comment: just use fully qualified name for newly created table! and obviously do not use `"` around it

Answer (score 0):

You miss the project name?

Or try to  remove the quotes.

Comment: I tried removing quotes, im still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try using backticks for your table name and remove the parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE `bikeshare_total` AS 
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Jan2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Feb2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.March2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.April2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.May2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.June2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.July2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.August2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Sep2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Oct2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Nov2021`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `cyclisticjan21-dec21.Bike_share.Dec2021`
;
```

Comment: Thank you! but i am receiving the same error- Table "bikeshare_total" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).

Comment: Then I suppose you haven't  specified a database to use after login. You can verify it by executing `select database();` . If null is returned ,  you need to assign a database to use. e.g `use testdb;`  Or you can directly create the table by qualifying the table name with a database name. e.g `create table \`testdb\`.\`bikeshare_total\` `